# landing page url parameter in angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My angular 2 project has only 1 page, so i did not use routing concept at all. But the landing page can either have a URL parameter or not have it. So how do i capture the URL parameter when routing is not used or do i need to use routing for this requirement. Based on availability of URL parameter i need to do extra action in page.

```
RouterModule.forRoot
```

Answer (score 0):

For example in your routing:

```
path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login',
{ path: 'login', component: InlogComponent }
```

In your other component you have function **logout()**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';    
constructor(private router: Router){}        
    private logout() {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
```

Comment: @RahulSingh I have no clue if it's the right answer but this is the basics.